# Add custom attributes to apacheds directory studio

Tags: ldap, jndi, apacheds

I am working on basic application for inserting records in apacheds directory studio (LDAP). I have followed [this](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/ldap-apache-directory-studio-basic.html) example it is working fine. Now I want to add custom attributes according to my requirements I found [this](http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-introduce-custom-attributes-to.html) article explaining the procedure to do so but it didn't work for me. I have also tried this using java code but the java code also does not insert custom attributes. Please can any one tell me good tutorial (JNDI or ldif class) for this so I can add my custom attributes.

Comment: You didn't provide information on why and how your attempt to change the directory schema to add new attributes failed. What do your schema changes look like? What are syntax, matching rules for your attributes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't provide information on why and how your attempt to change the directory schema to add new attributes failed. What do your schema changes look like? What are syntax, matching rules for your attributes?

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I probably didn't have enough reputation to comment on 05/31/2013.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this problem too, but second link worked for me, after I found out that I have to create unique OIDs (ep. 2.25.128424792425578037463837247958458780603.1)